# How to create custom administrator panel page/subpage?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling with creating custom subpages in wordpress admin panel. I'm interested in creating any custom subpage, which is going to look like a default administrator screens with some modifications. At best I'm trying to achieve custom comments subpage, showing comments related only to my custom post type I've created, but any tips on how to interrupt default render of admin screens in wp admin panel would be appreciated.

I'm not sure what hooks to use, or where are the files responsible for rendering pages like comments, posts, settings ect.

I want to see how they are written so I could possibly copy-paste the code and after some changes - callback it with the function "add_submenu_page()" or:

`add_comments_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);`

Any tips where to look hooks, files or information on how any page in panel admin is rendered would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!